# Recuperar datos relacionados con eloquent - Laravel 8

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

Estoy desarrollando un sistema similar a lo que seria un "playstore" para un proyecto académico. En la aplicación existen 2 tipos de usuarios, un usuario desarrollador que puede hacer un CRUD de aplicaciones para el sistema y otro usuario cliente, que puede ver y listar las apps de dichos desarrolladores (ambos tipos de usuarios están en la tabla Users, utilice el paquete de Roles de Spatie para diferenciarlos y que cada uno tenga su acceso a determinadas rutas, entiendo que esta no sea una buena practica, estoy en proceso de iteraciones).

He creado la migración de la tabla de aplicaciones con la clave foránea que apunta al id de usuario dentro del campo "created_by". La relación seria de 1 a N ya que 1 desarrollador puede estar relacionado con varias aplicaciones, y una aplicación esta relacionada con 1 desarrollador.

```
Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('category');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->text('logo_url');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
```

Acá defino la clave foránea en esta migración:

```
Schema::table('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('created_by');
        $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

Ahora defino las relaciones, en el modelo User:

```
public function apps() {
    return $this->hasMany(Application::class,'created_by');
}
```

Y en el modelo Application:

```
public function developer() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'created_by');
}
```

Ahora bien, el usuario al logearse como desarrollador, tiene que ser redirigido a una pagina en donde pueda ver las aplicaciones que creó, para realizar el CRUD correspondiente, **y en este punto es donde tengo básicamente mi problema**, no se si estoy utilizando correctamente eloquent (casi seguro que no xd), pero realice distintas pruebas que me llevan al mismo resultado indeseado. Lo que estoy buscando es enviar a la vista del usuario desarrollador, las aplicaciones que están relacionadas con su ID, que por ende será valor del campo "created_by" de la tabla applications anteriormente mencionada. Y de no existir ninguna aplicación para este desarrollador, mostrar un mensaje personalizado con un botón que apunte a la ruta correspondiente para crear su primer aplicación (aunque esto ultimo no es tan relevante quizá).

De momento lo que tengo en el controlador es esto:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function index(User $dev) {

        $appsDev = $dev::has('apps')->get();

        return view('dev.dashboard',compact('appsDev'));
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, al realizar un print_r de la variable appsDev en la vista, me encuentro con esta monstruosidad:

```
App\Models\User Object
            (
                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => name
                        [1] => surname
                        [2] => alias
                        [3] => email
                        [4] => password
                    )

                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => password
                        [1] => remember_token
                        [2] => two_factor_recovery_codes
                        [3] => two_factor_secret
                    )

                [casts:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [email_verified_at] => datetime
                    )

                [connection:protected] => mysql
                [table:protected] => users
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [incrementing] => 1
                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [withCount:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [name] => Esteban
                        [surname] => Perez
                        [alias] => Arrow
                        [email] => esteban@perez.com
                        [password] => testing1234
                        [two_factor_secret] => 
                        [two_factor_recovery_codes] => 
                        [remember_token] => 
                        [created_at] => 2021-03-15 03:46:24
                        [updated_at] => 2021-03-15 03:46:24
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [name] => Esteban
                        [surname] => Perez
                        [alias] => Arrow
                        [email] => esteban@perez.com
                        [password] => testing1234
                        [two_factor_secret] => 
                        [two_factor_recovery_codes] => 
                        [remember_token] => 
                        [created_at] => 2021-03-15 03:46:24
                        [updated_at] => 2021-03-15 03:46:24
                    )

                [changes:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [classCastCache:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [timestamps] => 1
                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )
```

Cabe aclarar que realice algunos insert para ver que me devolvía esto, estuve leyendo varios artículos y mirando tutoriales pero no encuentro solución alguna de momento, **¿Cómo puedo obtener los registros de las aplicaciones correspondientes al usuario logeado?.**

Comment: Si estoy usando Jetstream para los componentes y Laravel Fortify para el login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Probaste usando `with`? Con esa consulta lo que haces es devolver los usuarios que tengan apps, según entiendo.

Creo que si quieres ver si el usuario tiene apps, deberías hacer algo como esto `return auth()->user()->apps;`

Si tu estructura está bien hecha, si hay datos en ese usuario con esa relación, debe mostrarte los datos, sino, el resultado será null. Entonces en tu vista, puedes evaluar algo como esto;

```
{{ auth()->user()->apps ?? 'Otra Cosa' }}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona perfecto. Al final estaba consultando cualquier cosa con eloquent jaja.